# Clearing compiled java classes from the command prompt

Tags: java

In java, working from the command prompt, is there a way to clear compiled classes from memory?

I'm in a class that uses shared computers.  Since we all have the same homework we often end up with the same class names.  I'd like a way to clear any previously compiled classes that other students have done, so I can start fresh.

Example:  I have a class Bank that uses object of class Person.  If I sit down at the computer and someone else has already compiled a class Person how can I clear theirs and start fresh?

Comment: The school computers take forever to reboot, I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Someone with more knowledge may correct me, but shouldn't compiling your own Person class overwrite the existing file? 

If you're using Person, you'd presumably compile your own alongside Bank

Comment: @CubeJockey you are right

Comment: And they're not in the memory, they're on the filesystem.

Comment: Strange, I keep compiling mine but the output remains some old version.

Comment: Your professors are failing you. Please do some research on compilation, classes, class files, class path, java compiler, java interpreter (AKA JVM), OS processes.

Answer (score 0):

Java searches the classpath for classes, as long as your output directory is the first element on the classpath it will always be picked up first.   You can check the current classpath with `echo $CLASSPATH`.
Then you can reset it with
`set CLASSPATH=/path/to/my/output:$CLASSPATH`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out the previous guy never did the eject media button for his flash drive, so the computer didn't recognize my drive.  From the command prompt, trying to compile just does nothing...same as if it compiled with no errors but never actually overwrote the previous class.

This is probably a very isolated issue...school computers with maximum restrictions, plus working from the command prompt.

Anyway...lesson learned.